# Custom CSS breaks bootstrap modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created my own home automation web app. To authorize actions the user needs to enter a pin. Instead of using an input/password field I want to use a dial/number pad. 
I decided to go with [this snippet](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/iphone-number-pad). My big problem is: I'm not good with CSS. I understand HTML and can work with it (at least with Bootstrap). But I have not learned CSS yet.
But I want to display the number pad in a modal (which pops up when the user tries to press the "Turn of PC" button for example).

I copied the css and html from the link. But this is the outcome:
[image: Broken Modal]

Can someone explain me which part of the css is causing this?

Thanks

Comment: We need some code. Please make a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: or at least right click the whitespace of the pad element, inspect element in dev tools and show us the css affecting it.

Comment: Done: http://jsfiddle.net/3r2wure7/ But you need to go fullscreen to see the problem. In mobile it looks ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `<div class="container">` from the modal body, and change the class on your `phone` tag to `col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 phone`.

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3r2wure7/1/)
[Full-screen results](https://jsfiddle.net/3r2wure7/1/embedded/result/)

Comment: That's it! And I thought it was the CSS causing the problem. Thanks!